# Can't SSH to digital ocean new droplet

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I am trying to SSH to my Digital ocean droplet but it shows following error.

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xxx.x port 22: Operation timed out
```

I have already tried with the following commands. Nothing worked.

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

I have set up the SSH key.

Allowed 22 port with the below command

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your droplet's IP is `${DROPLET}` and the location of your Digital Ocean SSH private key is `${IDENTITY}`, then you should be able to:

```sh
ssh -i ${IDENTITY} root@${IP}
```

Comment: Please close off-topic questions. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.